# Input fields not responding to flexbox

Tags: html, css

I want to create 9 input fields for a product calculator that I'm building. I want to have 3 rows of three columns. However, for some reason when I apply display: flex and flex-direction: row to the parent div this doesn't work. All my input fields are placed in a column regardless of flex-direction and input sizing doesn't work

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.survery-questions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.home-price-footer {
    width: 25%;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}


#input {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="survery-questions">
        <form action="">
            <div class="price-form">
                <input name="price-1" type="text" placeholder="price 1" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>

            </div>
        
            <div class="phone-form">
                <input name="price-2" type="text" placeholder="price 2" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
        
            <div class="email-form">
                <input type="price-3" placeholder="price 3" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
            
                   <div class="price-form">
                <input name="price-4" type="text" placeholder="price 4" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>

            </div>
        
            <div class="phone-form">
                <input name="price-5" type="text" placeholder="price 5" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
        
            <div class="email-form">
                <input type="price-6" placeholder="price 6" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
                   <div class="price-form">
                <input name="price-7" type="text" placeholder="price 7" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>

            </div>
        
            <div class="phone-form">
                <input name="price-8" type="text" placeholder="price 8" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
        
            <div class="email-form">
                <input type="price-9" placeholder="price 9" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
        
                </form>
       </div>
       
        </form>
       </div>
       
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: BTW, typo: `survery` >> `survey`

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your html intact, A little modification was needed where you gave `display:flex`, basically the `display:flex` works for immediate children only and not the the sub-children so immediate child of `.survey-questions` was `<form>` and `<div>` are children to `<form>` hence I added `form` to your existing selector and gave an additional attribute `flex-wrap:wrap` to maintain rows and columns layout as you had expected.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* just a little modification in this part */
.survery-questions form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
form > div{
    width: 33.3%;
}

.home-price-footer {
    width: 25%;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}


#input {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="survery-questions">
        <form action="">
            <div class="price-form">
                <input name="price-1" type="text" placeholder="price 1" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>

            </div>
        
            <div class="phone-form">
                <input name="price-2" type="text" placeholder="price 2" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
        
            <div class="email-form">
                <input type="price-3" placeholder="price 3" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
            
                   <div class="price-form">
                <input name="price-4" type="text" placeholder="price 4" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>

            </div>
        
            <div class="phone-form">
                <input name="price-5" type="text" placeholder="price 5" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
        
            <div class="email-form">
                <input type="price-6" placeholder="price 6" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
                   <div class="price-form">
                <input name="price-7" type="text" placeholder="price 7" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>

            </div>
        
            <div class="phone-form">
                <input name="price-8" type="text" placeholder="price 8" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
        
            <div class="email-form">
                <input type="price-9" placeholder="price 9" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
            </div>
        
                </form>
       </div>
       
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: This certainly works, but for several reasons I've avoided using forms as layout elements. For one thing behavior can be unpredictable vs. a div--sometimes they don't take styling the same way. For another, if you decide to restructure the form (say to split it into two) you now have to modify your layout as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `<form>` element is the only child of your flex container, and is therefore the only element being influenced by it. By moving it outside the flex container things come closer to behaving as you'd like.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.survey-questions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* added */
}

.survey-questions > div {
    width: 33.33%; /* added */
    padding: 0 10px; /* added */
}

.home-price-footer {
    width: 100%; /* updated */

    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}

#input {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <div class="survey-questions">
        <div class="price-form">
            <input name="price-1" type="text" placeholder="price 1" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
        </div>

        <div class="phone-form">
            <input name="price-2" type="text" placeholder="price 2" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
        </div>

        <div class="email-form">
            <input type="price-3" placeholder="price 3" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
        </div>

        <div class="price-form">
            <input name="price-4" type="text" placeholder="price 4" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
        </div>

        <div class="phone-form">
            <input name="price-5" type="text" placeholder="price 5" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
        </div>

        <div class="email-form">
            <input type="price-6" placeholder="price 6" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
        </div>

        <div class="price-form">
            <input name="price-7" type="text" placeholder="price 7" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
        </div>

        <div class="phone-form">
            <input name="price-8" type="text" placeholder="price 8" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
        </div>

        <div class="email-form">
            <input type="price-9" placeholder="price 9" class="home-price-footer" id="input" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: For input fields for a calculator am I wrong to be using <form>?

Comment: No, but it may not be necessary. It can change the behavior of the Enter key and some other things if there's a form element present.